# PHP RegularExpression : match anything (including whitespaces)

Tags: php, pattern-matching, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
text text text
text text text

{test}
    content
    content
    content
{/test}

text text text
text text text
```

i need to get two separate results from the above string:
1.

```
{test}
    content
    content
    content
{/test}
```

2.

```
    content
    content
    content
```

so, what should be the two separate **regular expression patterns** for **PHP** to get the above two results

Comment: advice: Drop what you're doing and learn how to use regular expressions. They will make you very happy for the rest of your life.

Comment: You can match both with a single call to preg_match(); there isn't the need to use two different regular expressions, which would mean to call preg_match() twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
$str = <<<STR
text text text
text text text

{test}
    content
    content
    content
{/test}

text text text
text text text
STR;

$m = array();
if (preg_match('#\{([a-zA-Z]+)\}(.*?)\{/\1\}#ism', $str, $m)) {
    var_dump($m);
}
```

Which will get this kind of output :

```
array
  0 => string '{test}
    content
    content
    content
{/test}' (length=50)
  1 => string 'test' (length=4)
  2 => string '
    content
    content
    content
' (length=37)
```

So, in `$m[0]` you have the whole matched string *(ie tags+content)*, and in `$m[2]` you only have to content between the tags.

Note I have used "generic" tags, and not specifically "`test`" ; you can change that if you'll only have "`test`" tags.

For more informations, you can take a look at, at least :

- [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match)
- [Regular Expressions (Perl-Compatible)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)

Comment: oh, sorry, i used [.*?] instead of (.*?) and that was my fault! however, thanks for your nice reply!
would you please explain me the term {/\1}

Comment: The \1 is a "back reference" to the first pattern that was matched ; the idea here is that the closing tag should correspond to the opening tag ;; for more informations, you can read : http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php

Answer (score 1):

To capture the tags and contents together:

```
/(\{test\}[^\x00]*?\{\/test\})/
```

To capture just the contents:

```
/\{test\}([^\x00]*?)\{\/test\}/
```